# How to fix "Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." for React?

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack

My React app won't load the following script from my local folder. I updated webpack to version 4.0 and every time I try to load a script, it gives me the following error:

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/components/homepage/texting.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My React App</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0">

  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="./components/homepage/texting.js"></script>

</body>
```

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
    },

    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it! I just moved all the JavaScript to ComponentDidMount()

Comment: Are you saying this was caused by your React code being in the constructor? That seems a very unlikely solution. Nothing else you changed?